# Android : Does a Service gets killed when an Activity in the same process is closed?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

So here's my scenario...

I'm designing an android app with a few Activities for user interaction like configuration of the app and etc... And my app runs in the background (for a long time) using a Service.

From what i've researched so far, Services in Android run as long as it is not closed by OURselves or the SYSTEM. ( Never tested this though )

1. So my main question is, **Does the running service get closed if all the activities in my app are closed ?**
2. And i also came to know that both an Activity and a Service can't be run at the same time on the main process, **Is this true ?**
3. **For my scenario which design is best ?** Activity+Service in same process, Activity+ *IntentService* in same process, Activity, Service in diff processes ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Services in Android run as long as it is not closed by OURselves or the SYSTEM

Or by the user.

> Does the running service get closed if all the activities in my app are closed ?

If you used `startService()` to start the service, no. If you used `bindService()` and called `unbindService()` a matching number of times, then yes.

> And i also came to know that both an Activity and a Service can't be run at the same time on the main process, Is this true ?

An `Activity` is an object. A `Service` is an object. Objects do not "run" in Java (or any other OO language that I can think of). *Methods* run.

> For my scenario which design is best ? Activity+Service in same process, Activity+ IntentService in same process, Activity, Service in diff processes ?

"Activity+Service in same process".

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, what i meant to ask was, Whether a Activity and a Service can be STARTED at the same time in the same process ?

Comment: @Dreamer: "Whether a Activity and a Service can be STARTED at the same time in the same process ?" -- partially, that depends upon your definition of "the same time". On single-core CPUs, for example, no two things happen at "the same time". Partially, that depends on what you mean by "Service can be STARTED". Nothing starts your service unless *you* start it, such as by calling `startService()`. So, can your activity start a service in your process? Yes.